# How can I write a test with for a function which depends on the of return of other?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, jestjs, redux-saga

```js
export function* removeProfile(auth, database, action){
    try{  
        const url = `/users/${action.user.uid}` 

        const {ref} = database
        const result = yield call([database, ref], url)
        const {remove} = database.ref() 
        yield call([result, remove])   //how can i do a test for this case?   
    } catch({message}) {
        yield put(ActionCreator.removeProfileFailure(message))      
    }
}
```

I need to do a test of a function that depends on the response of another, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions).

Your `removeProfile` function is really easy to be (unit) tested because it has almost zero external dependencies (except for `ActionCreator`).

So you can pass a mocked version of `auth`, `database` and `action`. A mock is a function with the same signature of the original one but super easy to be instrumented.

There are a lot of ways to test a saga but with a simple saga like yours you can use [runSaga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#runsagaoptions-saga-args) that, as the name suggests, runs the whole saga without manually calling `saga.next(...)`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xwyjn41pz?module=%2Fsrc%2Fremove-profile.test.js&previewwindow=tests) you can find the working example of my test.

Take a look at the test I wrote

```
const { removeProfile } = require("./remove-profile");
const { runSaga } = require("redux-saga");

test("Mocking the database call", () => {
  const removeMock = jest.fn(() => ({
    // place here the remove's return value
  }));

  const databaseMock = {
    ref: url => ({
      remove: removeMock
    })
  };

  runSaga(
    {}, // options
    removeProfile, // your saga
    // below all the arguments for the saga
    null,
    databaseMock,
    { user: { uid: "999" } }
  );
  expect(removeMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Let me know if it's enough clear